# Convert timestamp to varchar

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I am writing a sql query in AWS Athena, where I have a timestamp field and I had to extract the dates of June 2021 (only dates, without time).

I am able to convert timestamp to date but then having trouble with converting to `varchar`.

Can anybody help please. Thanks in advance.

```
select substr(CAST(server_time AS VARCHAR)) from matomo_log_link_visit_action where server_time like "2021-06-%" ;
```

Comment: Please don't tag spam. if you are using AWS Athena, then don't tag completely unrelated technology such as [[tag:mysql]] and [[tag:sql-server]].

Comment: I think you need to supply additional parameters to `substr` for your SQL to work.  Something like `SBUSTR(CAST(server_time AS VARCHAR), 1, 20)`

Comment: Why do you need substring?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `format_datetime` function. For example:

```
select format_datetime(my_timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

see the docs: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

Comment: I need to put a condition on the timestamp field where I need dates from this month. I was thinking of converting timestamp to date first and then applying the required condition. 

It's throwing an error - Left side of LIKE expression must evaluate to a varchar (actual: timestamp). Any suggestions?

""select format_datetime(server_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd') from  test where idsite=3 and server_time like '2020-06-%'""

Comment: you can use `where format_datetime(mytimestamp, 'yyyy-MM') ='2020-06'`